# Generate random numbers in C++ at compile time

Tags: c++, random, c++11, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to precompute random values using C++11's `random` library at compile time. I'm mostly following examples. What am I doing wrong here?

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>

vector<double> rands;
typedef std::mt19937_64 RNG;
uint64_t seed_val;
RNG rng; 

void initialize() {
     rng.seed(seed_val);
}

constexpr vector<double> generate_random( )                 //size_t numbers)
{   
    int numbers = 1000;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> zero_one(0.0, 1.0);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) { 
             double rand_num = zero_one(rng);
             rands.push_back( rand_num );
    }
    return rands;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "TMP rands";
    for_each( rands.begin(), rands.end(), [] (double value)
    {
        cout<<value<<endl;
    });
}
```

Here's an example compile-time random number generator shamelessly stolen from [here](http://eden.dei.uc.pt/~sneves/pubs/2012-snfa2.pdf), but thought it might be useful for anyone who looks this up:

```
template<u32 S, u32 A = 16807UL, u32 C = 0UL, u32 M = (1UL<<31)-1>
struct LinearGenerator {
    static const u32 state = ((u64)S * A + C) % M;
    static const u32 value = state;
    typedef LinearGenerator<state> next;
    struct Split { // Leapfrog
        typedef LinearGenerator< state, A*A, 0, M> Gen1;
        typedef LinearGenerator<next::state, A*A, 0, M> Gen2;
    };
};
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is it not compiling? Is it giving the wrong output?

Comment: `system_clock::now()` and now please tell me how this call could ever happen at compile-time.

Comment: You also need to read up on how `constexpr` functions have to be structured, they're basically only allowed to be a single `return` statement. Also, please refrain from [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/500104). :)

Comment: There's also no template meta-programming involved here - just constexpr.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why the initial lambda call? Why not just call `cout` directly instead of by a lambda?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i'm trying to teach my self the new standard and the lambda's produce cleaner code for the vector for_each

Comment: @Xeo then would it be possible to return the entire c++ rands vector?

Comment: I think @Joachim's actual question was about the lambda that just prints something. Don't make this more complicated than it needs to be. Edited it out again.

Comment: This will hopefully be built into compilers once C++11 becomes more mainstream.  People have already expressed desire for this feature: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2009-04/msg00116.html.

Others have written libraries of contexpr functions, but all seem to leave out random numbers.  It has been talked about as a possible item to include in the standard library: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2994.htm

Comment: @pyCthon: "the lambda's produce cleaner code for the vector for_each" Or you could just use range-based for loops and have your code work that much better and look that much cleaner.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk Don't hope for it. This won't be built into compilers anytime soon, because: #1 it's not in the standard, and won't be anytime soon because #2 constexpr is already incredibly hard to implement as is, and isn't likely to change anytime soon (just ask compiler implementers about it), and #3 generating random numbers at compile-time is far from a common necessity (and personally, I can't think of a real use case for them, but that may be some bias).

Comment: worth having a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpn_5Mrrxf8)

Comment: Can you show sample usage for the last code snippet? Your link is 404

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Only `constexpr` functions and constant expressions may be evaluated at compile time. That rules out `<chrono>` and `<random>`.

What you can do is access the `__TIME__` preprocessor macro and define your own PRNG composed of one-line, `constexpr` functions.

Comment: would seeding the random library the alternative way with out chronos work? say from the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114043/random-number-generation-in-c11-how-to-generate-how-they-work

Comment: or use the tedious but known method of *template-meta-programming* to implement a *compile-time* SRNG.

Comment: @refp any reference's or link's?

Comment: @pyCthon nope, but I could write you a working example and post it if you'd like.. with proper information on how it works.

Comment: @pyCthon What does that Q&A have to do with seeding? You can seed with any data you have available, but need to seed with something, and `__TIME__` the only viable candidate. There is no need for templates here, only `constexpr`, and you might also want `__COUNTER__` or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166337/does-c-support-compile-time-counters . But I don't know of a prefab solution. It's a somewhat obscure problem.

Comment: @pyCthon To avoid string processing annoyances, you might define a function or macro that just returns `__TIME__[n]`. Then hash the relevant digits. In fact, `constexpr` is probably overkill, the entire PRNG is probably elegantly done as a macro. That way you can also factor in `__LINE__`. It depends what sort of randomness you want.

Answer (score 9):

There is a research paper on the topic: [Random number generator for C++ template metaprograms](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/259005783_Random_number_generator_for_C_template_metaprograms)
containing [code snippet](https://github.com/cr-lupin/metarand) for the `__TIME__` trick. It also talks about supporting different random number engines and distributions as orthogonal choices.

Answer (score 5):

I would try pulling it in from an external source.  A very simple example is to compile your program with defined macro variables in the compile command.  Here `$RANDOM` is a special built-in variable in unix/linux systems that automatically returns a random 16-bit number.

```
g++ -D__RANDOM__=$RANDOM yourprog.cpp -o yourprog

//yourprog.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "Random variable " << __RANDOM__ << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You can also write your own script or executable to assign to your macro variable.

```
//DevRandomGenerator.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class DevRandom {
private:
    std::ifstream stream;
public:

    DevRandom() {
        stream.open("/dev/urandom",std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
    }

    unsigned int unsignedInt() {
        unsigned int u = 0;
        stream.read((char*)&u, sizeof(unsigned int));
        return u;
    }
};

int main() {
  DevRandom rand;
  std::cout << rand.unsignedInt() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

then compile as:

```
g++ DevRandomGenerator.cpp -o DevRandomGenerator
g++ -D__RANDOM__="$(./DevRandomGenerator)" yourprog.cpp -o yourprog
```

A better random generator would be to write a program that uses audio and visual inputs.

Comment: A global name starting `_` and followed by a capital letter is reserved to the implementation, so your solution has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It starts with two `_`s.

Comment: @IllidanS4: Good spot. [The name is still reserved, though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/560648).

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is five years old, and already has an accepted answer.  Even so, I would like to add that it certainly **is possible** to generate random numbers at compile time, with the understanding that you'll get the same sequence of random numbers each time you run the program.  To put it simply, if the seed is known at compile time, the compiler is **allowed** to figure out what random numbers will be output, and just turn the program into "output this sequence of numbers."

Compilers will have limits to how aggressively they optimize, so I can't promise that they will always make this substitution, and I doubt any compiler would be able to make the substitution for something as complex as the Mersenne Twister, but something simpler like `linear_congruential_engine` has a chance (also, the only way to be sure that it happened would be to have the compiler output assembly code, and then you look at the assembly code).

I know this is possible because I implemented a random generator modeled after `random_device` that used [Marsaglia's Xorshift algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift).  Since Marsaglia's paper actually included multiple related algorithms, I had the class take a template parameter to select which shift pattern to use.  I wanted to know if the compiler would optimize out the `switch` statement I used.  I forgot to pass a seed, so the compiler used the default, i.e., the seed was known at compile time.  When I looked at the assembly code, not only was the `switch` gone, but GCC had optimized the program into "output these three numbers."

The final version of the program listed in the question never actually called the functions to generate the sequence of numbers, and never called the function to seed the generator.  This version will do that, but I doubt it will be turned into "print this sequence of random numbers."

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <random>

int get_seed()
{
    int hour = std::atoi(__TIME__);
    int min = std::atoi(__TIME__ + 3);
    int sec = std::atoi(__TIME__ + 6);
    return 10000 * hour + 100 * min + sec;
}

int main()
{
    // get_seed() returns an int based on __TIME__ (a string literal
    // set by the preprocessor), which is known at compile time.
    //
    // Also, w/r/t the engines in <random>: not setting a seed explicitly
    // will use a default seed, which is known at compile time.  So if
    // you're OK getting the same sequence of numbers for any compilation,
    // then "std::mt19937_64 rng;" may be all you need.
    std::mt19937_64 rng(get_seed());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> zero_one(0.0, 1.0);
    const int COUNT = 1000;
    std::generate_n(std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n"), COUNT,
        [&rng, &zero_one]() { return zero_one(rng); });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although your answer is valid in general, the code you wrote does nothing at compile time.

Comment: The question is asking a compile time function, instead of runtime function. Seed-generation is the least to worry about.

Answer (score 4):

This question may now be nine years old but I still did not find any satisfying solution so I implemented a reliable compile time random generator as a single header library myself. It uses KISS random generator and represents its internal state as a parameterized type. The state is pseudo remembered using the counter macro.
`CTRandomTimeSeed` is an attempt to implement a varring seed between multiple compilations. Additionally a custom seed can be defined using `DYNLEC_CUSTOM_RANDOM_SEED`.

```
#pragma once

#include <cstdint>

// all numbers are generated randomly at compile time. the internal state is pseudo
// remembered using the counter macro. the seed is based on time using the timestamp
// and time macro. additionally a custom random seed can be specified to fully rely

#ifndef DYNLEC_CUSTOM_RANDOM_SEED
#define DYNLEC_CUSTOM_RANDOM_SEED 0xbdacf99b3f7a1bb4ULL
#endif

// just iterating over the macros will always result in same
// number because the internal state is only updated for each occurance
// of the following macros

// generates a random number seeded with time and the custom seed
#define DYC_RAND_NEXT (::Dynlec::CTRandomGeneratorValueSeeded<__COUNTER__>)
// generates a random number seeded with time and the custom seed between min and max ( [min, max[ )
#define DYC_RAND_NEXT_BETWEEN(min, max) (min + (::Dynlec::CTRandomGeneratorValueSeeded<__COUNTER__> % (max - min)))
// generates a random number seeded with time and the custom seed with a limit ( [0, limit[ )
#define DYC_RAND_NEXT_LIMIT(limit) DYC_RAND_NEXT_BETWEEN(0, limit)
// helper macro for non repetetive indexed values
#define DYC_RAND_INDEXED(index) (::Dynlec::CTRandomGeneratorValue<index, ::Dynlec::CTRandomSeed ^ DYC_RAND_NEXT>)
// helper macro for non repetetive random streams
#define DYC_RAND_STREAM(n, callback) (::Dynlec::CTRandomStream<n, ::Dynlec::CTRandomSeed ^ DYC_RAND_NEXT>)

namespace Dynlec
{
    // the random generator internal state is represented by
    // the CTRandomGeneratorRaw type with each of its values
    // x, y, z and c
    template <
        uint64_t x, 
        uint64_t y, 
        uint64_t z, 
        uint64_t c>
    class CTRandomGeneratorRaw
    {
        static_assert(y != 0, 
            "CompileTimeRandom can not be used with 'y' equals 0");
        static_assert(z != 0 || c != 0,
            "CompileTimeRandom can not be used with 'z' and 'c' equals 0");
    public:
        typedef CTRandomGeneratorRaw<
            6906969069ULL * x + 1234567ULL,
            ((y ^ (y << 13)) ^ ((y ^ (y << 13)) >> 17)) ^ (((y ^ (y << 13)) ^ ((y ^ (y << 13)) >> 17)) << 43),
            z + ((z << 58) + c),
            ((z + ((z << 58) + c)) >> 6) + (z + ((z << 58) + c) < ((z << 58) + c))> Next;

        constexpr static uint64_t Value = x + y + z;
    };

    // to prevent any accidental selection of invalid parameters
    // these values are omitted
    template <
        uint64_t x,
        uint64_t y,
        uint64_t z,
        uint64_t c>
    class CTRandomGeneratorRawSafe
        :
        public CTRandomGeneratorRaw<
            x, (y == 0) ? 1 : y, (z == 0 && c == 0) ? 1 : z, c>
    {
    };

    // CTRandomGenerator is used to quickly compute the nth iteration
    // of CTRandomGeneratorSafeRaw based on a single uint64_t seed
    template <uint64_t iterations, uint64_t seed>
    class CTRandomGenerator
    {
        friend CTRandomGenerator<iterations + 1, seed>;
        typedef typename CTRandomGenerator<iterations - 1, seed>::Current::Next Current;

    public:
        constexpr static uint64_t Value = Current::Value;
    };

    template <uint64_t seed>
    class CTRandomGenerator<0ULL, seed>
    {
        friend CTRandomGenerator<1ULL, seed>;

        typedef typename CTRandomGeneratorRawSafe<
            seed ^ 1066149217761810ULL,
            seed ^ 362436362436362436ULL,
            seed ^ 1234567890987654321ULL,
            seed ^ 123456123456123456ULL>::Next Current;

    public:
        constexpr static uint64_t Value = Current::Value;
    };

    template <uint64_t iteration, uint64_t seed>
    constexpr static uint64_t CTRandomGeneratorValue = CTRandomGenerator<iteration, seed>::Value;

    const uint64_t CTRandomTimeSeed = 
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIME__[0]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIME__[1]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIME__[3]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIME__[4]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIME__[6]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIME__[7])>>>>>> ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIMESTAMP__[0]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIMESTAMP__[1]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIMESTAMP__[2]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIMESTAMP__[4]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIMESTAMP__[5]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIMESTAMP__[6])>>>>>> ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIMESTAMP__[8]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIMESTAMP__[9]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIMESTAMP__[20]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIMESTAMP__[21]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIMESTAMP__[22]) ^
        CTRandomGeneratorValue<0, (__TIMESTAMP__[23])>>>>>>;

    const uint64_t CTRandomSeed = (DYNLEC_CUSTOM_RANDOM_SEED ^ CTRandomTimeSeed);

    template <uint64_t iteration>
    constexpr static uint64_t CTRandomGeneratorValueSeeded = CTRandomGeneratorValue<iteration, CTRandomSeed>;

    template <uint64_t n, uint64_t seed = ::Dynlec::CTRandomSeed>
    struct CTRandomStream
    {
        // callback(uint64_t index [0;n[, uint64_t random_number)
        template <typename T>
        static void Call(T callback)
        {
            CTRandomStream<n - 1, seed>::Call(callback);
            callback(n - 1, CTRandomGeneratorValue<n, seed>);
        }
    };

    template <uint64_t seed>
    struct CTRandomStream<0, seed>
    {
        template <typename T>
        static void Call(T callback) { }
    };
}
```

Usage example:

```
// random 64 bit number
std::cout << DYC_RAND_NEXT << std::endl;

// random 64 bit number between [0 and 10[
std::cout << DYC_RAND_NEXT_LIMIT(10) << std::endl;

// random 64 bit number between [1 and 10]
std::cout << DYC_RAND_NEXT_BETWEEN(1, 11) << std::endl;

// initialize array with random numbers
int array[50];

Dynlec::CTRandomStream<50>::Call([&array](uint64_t index, uint64_t n)
    { 
        array[index] = n;
    });
```

[Link](https://github.com/phisn/CompileTimeRandom) to the github project containing the project.

Answer (score 3):

Not just is `system_clock::now()` not compile-time knowable, but your function is labeled as returning a bool, but has no return statement anywhere.

Comment: i got rid of chronos now , thanks will update with out it , would it be possible to make the return type an entire c++ vector?

Comment: You can only call constexpr functions from your code, so if the vector functions are constexpr, you can.

Comment: ok so I can't use constexpr but would my ideas work with std templates?

Answer (score 1):

As per the error message:

```
cpp11tmprands.cpp:22:15: error: ‘rands’ was not declared in this scope
```

The variable `rands` is not declared in the scope of `main`. Make it a global variable instead of local in `generate_random` and that error will go away.