# Initializing a static member with a random value

Tags: c++, random, static, polymorphism

```
class A{
        int a;
    public:
        A(int inA = 0);
        int getA;
    protected:
        void setA(int inA);
    };
A::A(int inA)
    {
        setA(inA)
    }
void A::setA(int inA){
        //need to set a as static random number
        a = inA;
    }
int A::getA()const
    {
        return a;
    }
```

How could I possibly generate a random using a static member for a? I have seen something like this online: [Random Number In-Class Initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489392/random-number-in-class-initialisation) but not really sure how to use it.

Comment: Nothing here is static.

Comment: @JamesRoot how do I start?

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to start... do you want to initialize a static member, are you wondering if it's possible to initialize a static member with a random value, are you trying to seed an engine with a static member, or are you wondering how to create random values?

Comment: @james root as you said, if it's possible to initialize a static member with a random value. Any references or examples?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is probably to make global instances of the PRNG classes.

```
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;
std::mt19937 rng((std::random_device()()));

struct foo
{
    static int bar;
};

int foo::bar = dist(rng);
```

Of course, put the global objects and initialization in a .cpp file (thanks @AnonMail!).

Using the old (bad) random number facilities, you could use:

```
int foo::bar = (srand(time(0)), rand());
```

This is also not great because you've secretly seeded `srand` which is sort of weird, and `rand` is bad.

The (arguably) fun way is to do this:

```
int foo::bar = []() {std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist; std::mt19937 mt((std::random_device()())); return dist(mt); }();
```

You use a lambda to create the variables and return the value, eliminating extra objects and putting it all on one line.

I realized I don't think I've seen a lambda used like this before, so I wasn't sure if it would work. My compiler seems fine with it, and it runs as intended, so my assumption would be this is correct.

Comment: Your global objects need not be.  They can be placed in an anonymous namespace in foo's cpp file.

Comment: @AnonMail True, for some reason I forgot about something like that.