# How to randomly initialize a constant data member?

Tags: c++, random, initialization

Interface

```
class FireSimulator
{
    Landscape **forest;
    Weather w;
    static int statistics;
    const int x;
    const int y;

public:
    FireSimulator();
    FireSimulator(Weather&, int, int);

   void setBoundary();
   void Print();
};
```

Implementation

```
FireSimulator::FireSimulator() : w(),x(0),y(0)
{}

FireSimulator::FireSimulator(Weather& W, int X, int Y): w(W), x(X),y(Y)
{
    forest=new Landscape *[x];
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
    {
        forest[i]=new Landscape[y];
    }
}

void FireSimulator::setBoundary()
{}

void FireSimulator::Print()
{}

int FireSimulator::statistics=0;
```

This sets the forest of type landscape dynamically.

How do I use randomization to spread the trees around the forest?

How do I randomly initialize x and y in the constructor, which are constant data members?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a function `randomInt()` returning a random integer, you could just initialize the constant members to its return value:

```
FireSimulator::FireSimulator()
     : w()
     , x(randomInt())
     , y(randomInt())
{}
```

For non-cryptographic randomness, the C standard library `rand()` function might be good enough for your case if well seeded with `srand()`. These two functions are available from `#include <cstdlib>`. In C++11 also provides its own randomness generation methods in `<random>` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489392/random-number-in-class-initialisation)).

Comment: So I can just do it in the "get" function and call it in the member initialize list?

Comment: @Firdaws I'm sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: Thanks, it worked !! What I meant was, can I implement the randomization in the getter function of x and then just call it in the constructor? But, it's the same thing, so thanks :)

Comment: I don't think it would be a good practice for a getter like `getX()` to set `x` to a random value every time it is called.

Comment: So, in the setter then? Done :)