# Random array compile time

Tags: c++, templates

I have been fiddling with this problem for a while of generating an array of a compile time constant size containing unique random integers up to a compile time constant value. I have a nice templated rng, that I butchered from a paper, but haven't figured out the rest. This is probably a stupid question but - is this endeavour theoretically possible in c++, or have I missed something silly?

Edit: if it is possible please no spoilers

Comment: so, you want an array to have randomly-generated values at compile-time?

Comment: yes indeed i do

Comment: I'd rather did it with some shell script + `make(1)`

Comment: I am a metaprogramming noob.

Comment: you could build something off of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11498304/generate-random-numbers-in-c-at-compile-time

Comment: If you have a templated RNG then you're pretty much done, aren't you? Just value-initialise the array

Comment: ok, thanks @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just wanted to know it was possible. The issue with the rng is that it is self seeding (not unlike the linked answer). So I needed a  recursive solution to build the array and was messing it up. Too tired to figure it out now, just wanted to know if I was wasting my time as I haven't readily found similar endeavours online

Comment: Well don't quote me on it; I don't generally have time for gimmicks like this, so I've never tried it ;) But I can't think of any reason it shouldn't work (FSVO "work"; I can't see how useful it'd be).

Comment: I've done this with Visual C++ 2015, using timestamp macros for seeding the compile-time RNG implemented with template metaprogramming.  Seeding from char arrays relied on being able to access elements at compile-time, which is possible with VS2015, but not with previous versions, and I don't remember if I tried it with GCC.  I pretty much abandoned the project as soon as I got it to work, because it didn't seem very useful.

Comment: I will let you know if I find a use....

Comment: Yeah, let me know.  And don't get me wrong, I'm all for cool but useless.  It's kinda like climbing a mountain just to reach the summit.