# RTTI type tagging classes and functions

Tags: c++, rtti

what could be a good custom RTTI-like functionality without using 3rd party library or meta compiler?

I want to create a 32 bit TAG/ uuid for each class and function within a class and later use it for debugging or logging purpose.

<sub>please note: RTTI is not suitable for me hence this question; please don't mark this duplicate</sub>

Comment: As long as you're relying on nothing but C++, and want to generate IDs (though not necessarily UUIDs), this might be a useful post to check out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6174263/1467466