# C++ construct that behaves like the __COUNTER__ macro

Tags: c++, templates, macros, template-meta-programming

I have a set of C++ classes and each one must declare a unique sequential id as a compile-time constant.
For that I'm using the `__COUNTER__` built-in macro which translates to an integer that is incremented for every occurrence of it. The ids need not to follow a strict order. The only requirement is that they are sequential and start from 0:

```
class A {
public:
    enum { id = __COUNTER__ };
};

class B {
public:
    enum { id = __COUNTER__ };
};

// etcetera ...
```

My question is: Is there a way to achieve the same result using a C++ construct, such as templates?

Comment: What's wrong with `__COUNTER__`

Comment: Nothing wrong, but if there is a C++ way of doing it, I'd prefer, for consistency. Also, I'm not sure of how portable `__COUNTER__` is.

Comment: Probably not, also, what are you going to use it for? I have a hard time seeing the macro generating unique IDs across library boundaries.

Comment: I would say the lack of such a construct is why `__COUNTER__` exists.

Comment: what about `typeid()` ? `type_info` isn't an integer, I know, but there is a `bool operator==(const type_info&)` ... nop?

Comment: `__COUNTER__` is supported in Gnu CC (gcc) and from what I see in @Cheers comment below, also in Visual Studio -- so pretty portable.. unless you plan to go to a non-linux or windows based system.

Comment: an answer for C++17 onward. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69996234/5556374

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible way to do it using `__LINE__` macro and templates:

```
template <int>
struct Inc
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};

template <int index>
struct Id
{
    enum { value = Id<index - 1>::value + Inc<index - 1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Id<0>
{
    enum { value = 0 };
};

#define CLASS_DECLARATION(Class) \
template <> \
struct Inc<__LINE__> \
{ \
    enum { value = 1 }; \
}; \
 \
struct Class \
{ \
    enum { id = Id<__LINE__>::value }; \
private:
```

Example of using:

```
CLASS_DECLARATION(A)
    // ...
};

CLASS_DECLARATION(B)
    // ...
};

CLASS_DECLARATION(C)
    // ...
};
```

See [live example](http://ideone.com/vGecWh).

Answer (score 3):

Is a explicit chaining acceptable?

```
class A {
public:
    static const unsigned int id = 1;
};

class B {
public:
    static const unsigned int id = A::id+1;
};
```

The advantage of this approach is that you always get the same Id and you know what it is no matter what your compiler is. While with `__LINE__` or `__COUNTER__` approach may not be so predicatable. The disadvantage is that with chaining your class must always know the previous one on the chain.

Playing with templates (and C++11):

```
template <typename... T>
class Identificable;

template <>
class Identificable<> {
public:
    static const unsigned int id = 1;   
};

template <typename Prev>
class Identificable<Prev> {
public:
    static const unsigned int id = Prev::id+1;
};

class A : public Identificable<> {
public:
};

class B : public Identificable<A> {
public:
};
```

Comment: Yes, thanks @André. Had thought about explicit chaining like this. It is a valid tradeoff, if you are willing to add some coupling. Also, it is a deterministic setup. +1 to that!

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ has the **`__LINE__`** macro.

That is, `__LINE__` is a "C++ construct", as requested, in contrast to `__COUNTER__`, which isn't.

`__LINE__` differs from Visual C++’s `__COUNTER__` in that at least earlier versions of Visual C++ produced garbled expansions of `__LINE__` when a certain compilation option was used.

---

Depeneding on your needs you may however be able to simply use `type_info` instances for identification. C++11 added general support for comparing `type_info`, called **`std::typeindex`**. This means you can use standard collections.

Comment: `__LINE__` is out of the question. I need a sequential number, since I intend to index some arrays with it. Also, it must start at a known value, preferably 0. Sorry if I was unclear by "C++ construct". By that I meant something that is unique of C++, such as templates. Yes, a macro is part of C++, but it is also an inheritance from C.

Comment: @glampert: I think you can use `typeindex` as key for a `std::map`. For that matter you can use `__LINE__` numbers as keys. But in contrast to `typeindex` it might be difficult to ensure they're unique if classes not define in same translation unit.

Comment: Yes, `typeindex` seems pretty neat. That's why I upvoted. But I wonder if there is some way of doing it using template metaprogramming...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to achieve the same result using a C++ construct, such
>   as templates?

Yes, there is :-) The basic idea is to use chaining allocated IDs, which avoids the use of `__COUNTER__`, `__LINE__` or other approaches proposed earlier and does not require injecting "extra" info into the type definition.

Here is a brief description of the solution proposed in [v1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26661209/2527301) for the counter implemented on C++03, using template metaprograming. Two template specializations `ID_by_T` and `T_by_ID` are used to define links `type <=> ID` at compile time. The type's ID is a enum constant. If the link was not defined, `ID_by_T<type>::ID` returns `-1`, and `T_by_ID<undefinedID>::type` returns the `null_t` predefined type. The macro `DEF_TYPE_ID(type_name)` generates a new `ID` at the point of the definition the `type <=> ID` link.

This approach is based on a macro redefinition: When a macro is undefined using `#undef`, its value is expanded into the C++ code. For instance:

```
DEF_TYPE_ID(int)
#undef  PREV_TYPE
#define PREV_TYPE int
```

Macro `DEF_TYPE_ID` uses the following call to the previous definition of macro `PREV_TYPE`: `ID_T_pair<type_name, ID_by_T<PREV_TYPE>::ID+1>`. That is why I said about chaining allocated IDs.