# How to have a static counter for global types?

Tags: c++, templates, static

I'd like a static counter that is incremented each time I create another type, class. Here is what I've tried:

```
template <typename Type>
class Sequential_ID_Dispenser
{public:
    static inline int nextDispensed = 0;
    static int getID() { return nextDispensed++; }
};

struct DummyTypeForComponentIDs {}; // So that the same type is passed to getID()

template <typename T>
struct Component { 
    static inline int componentTypeID = Sequential_ID_Dispenser<DummyTypeForComponentIDs>::getID();
    
    
};

// The reason I've made it inherit like this is so that any time I add a new Component type/struct it'll automatically get an ID for that type
struct Hat : Component<Hat> {};
struct Tie : Component<Tie> {};

int main()
{
    

    int id = Hat::componentTypeID; // = 0
    id = Tie::componentTypeID; // = 1
}
```

This works. But I want to have the option of easily inheriting from any other component, and it doesn't work like this, for example:

```
template <typename T>
    struct Component { 
        static inline int componentTypeID = Sequential_ID_Dispenser<DummyTypeForComponentIDs>::getID();
   };

    struct Hat : Component<Hat> {};
    struct Tie : Component<Tie> {};
    struct BlueHat : Hat {};

int main()
{
    int id = Hat::componentTypeID; // = 0
    id = Tie::componentTypeID; // = 1
    
    id = BlueHat::componentTypeID; // = 0, gets the same number as struct Hat : Component<Hat>{}
}
```

Is there a good solution for this? I'd like to ideally just define any new struct without passing arguments to the base constructor. I realise that I've CRTP for this, it's just what I did to make it work, but there must be simpler way, right?

Edit: Actually I'm surprised the solution isn't easier, all I'd like is for each class I create in the global namespace to get a new ID, I guess either compile time or runtime.

Comment: No clue, but this is a problem that must stem from a really, really neat use case.

Comment: Do you want it to be known at compile time?

Comment: How about `struct BlueHat : Hat, Component<BlueHat> {};`?

Comment: @Jarod42 Isn't that inheriting from Component twice?

Comment: True, but `Component` is an empty class (and could be a simple traits instead BTW or template variable).

Comment: @Zebrafish _"thought this was CRTP struct Hat : Component<Hat> {};"_ It is. I don't know why πάντα ῥεῖ thinks it isn't.

Comment: @Asteroids _@Zebra_ Sorry, you're right. It in fact is the CRTP.. But it doesn't infer something like `T::static_ounter`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What you put _in_ the CRTP'd base class is orthogonal to the pattern itself. Just like your choice of types of data members is not defined by OO.

Comment: You might be interested by [compile-time-template-stdintegral-constant-counter-how-to-implement-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916933/compile-time-template-stdintegral-constant-counter-how-to-implement-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need inheritance for (runtime) counters on types.

You might even use a template variable (C++14):

```
std::size_t getId()
{
    static std::size_t counter = 0;
    return counter++;
}

template <typename T>
std::size_t Id = getId();
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/531a481375d3164a).

Answer (score 1):

I can't see an easy way to extend your current solution to do this, unless you want to start throwing `virtual` on every inheritance declarator, *and remember to do this each time*.

It seems like a bit of an anti-pattern to "count types", anyway. We already have unique type identifiers, by way of [`typeid`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid).

If you really need an `int`, you can have some manager class that takes a `std::type_info` and gives you an `int` unique to that type, possibly using a map to power it. But if you can just store the `std::type_info` in the first place instead, so much the better. The downside is that this information won't be available statically (i.e. "at compile-time").

Comment: Not as good as Jarod's solution, but is any of this actually wrong? Some valid alternative approaches (virtual inheritance fixes the original problem, and `type_info` _is_ the proper way to identify types). A downvote seems a bit much.