# How can I generate dense unique type IDs at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make a system of classes that are small objects, and the base class has a member that is a unique identifier that identifies the class:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    unsigned char id;
};

template <typename T>
class Triangle : public Shape
{
    T triangle_data;
};

template <typename T>
class Square : public Shape
{
    T square_data;
};

template <typename T>
class ShapeBox : public Shape
{
    T shapebox_data;
    Shape * child_shape;
};
```

With the class identifier, I go through a vector of Shape * and switch on the id visible in the base class, then static cast for different behavior (to Triangle, Square, or ShapeBox and child shapes held in it respectively for the example class hierarchy)

I could turn on RTTI, but the space cost seems fairly large, especially when the type information can be implemented as a pointer and the object size might be no bigger than a couple of bytes. There may be millions of small objects, and I really only need static cast anyways.

Currently I can make type identifiers by using statics that are assigned values from a static monotonically incrementing counter:

```
class TypeID
{
    static size_t counter;

public:
    template<typename T>
    static size_t value()
    {
        static size_t id = counter++;
        return id;
    }
};
size_t TypeID::counter = 1;
```

Ideally I want dense, unique type ID's that are available at compile time, so the compiler can perform well, like converting a switch on the type IDs into a constant time jump table, or at least a binary search tree rather than a linear time if/else chain for what might be a long list of type IDs...

I can use boilerplate at compile time to manually assign every type ID, or I can use object/function pointers from a similar type ID class. Boiler plate is guaranteed to be dense (because we assign it manually) and known at compile time, but it's unmaintainable for template types. Whenever you add a template type to a shape, you have to manually add a new type. The monotonic static counter is maintainable and dense, but unknown at compile time and so compile time optimizations aren't possible, and thread safety may be a concern. The function pointer ID is known at compile time and maintainable, but isn't dense and won't fit into a small id type like a char.

Is there any way to generate type IDs that are visible to the compiler at compile time, dense, and automatically assigned, perhaps using template metaprogramming counter or some preprocessor magic in C++11 or C++14? Or is this not possible until C++ has compile time reflection?

Comment: So essentially you're asking to create runtime class attributes at compile time? How should this work?

Comment: These are compile time class attributes, the compiler knows about them. It can count all the classes that derive from Shape. I just want to be able to get the information the compiler already has. This might fall under compile time reflection that's proposed for C++1z, but I'm hoping there's some way to do a monotonic counter for a class hierarchy at compile time.

Comment: The compiler can only count the classes derived from Shape in the current compilation unit. Would `Square<int>` and `Square<double>` have the same id?

Comment: No, otherwise your cast would be wrong, just as a Square<int> member function points to a different function pointer than Square<double> member function under the one definition rule as I understand it.

Comment: The answers to the following questions may be helpful: [Does C++ support compile-time counters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6166337/3043539) and [C++ construct that behaves like the __COUNTER__ macro](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23206580/3043539).

Comment: This seems like exactly what you want: http://youtu.be/Dsgws5zJiwk?t=35m9s , the [slides are here](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/tree/master/Presentations/Embind%20and%20Emscripten)

Comment: With padding your object might not be any smaller, even after you replace a pointer with a char.

Comment: I don't think this can be done _period_, because if I compile library A with derived types, and you compile library B with different derived types, and we ship them to Matt who links them both into his binary, there's going to be collisions on the IDs.  The only way to resolve this is if the enumeration values aren't resolved until _link time_, which means your switch statements can't be fully evaluated at compile time.  I don't think dense IDs are going to be possible without a predetermined enumeration.

Comment: Yeah, I think this needs compile time reflection, and resolving at link time the way member function pointers are resolved, so C++1z or later.

Comment: would explicit chaining of known types be ok, or is this not automatic enough for you? do you want to distribute the shapes across different compilation units, should it be extensible for users (i.e.: library code?) ?

Comment: @Mooing Duck  Thank!  Now it is 2017, is it possible with C++1z (or later)?

Comment: @PeterT From the CppCon2014 slide in your link, the provided id is an address. (time=35:46) It is not dense. `:(`

Comment: @cppBeginner: The idea is so far outside of how C++ works that I highly doubt it will ever occur. It's definitely not in C++17, and not in the plans for C++20. In practice, dynamic ids work just fine, so there doesn't seem much need to change how C++ works to solve this.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to generate type IDs that are visible to the compiler
>   at compile time, dense, and automatically assigned, perhaps using
>   template metaprogramming counter

I've developed a code which does this with few restrictions.
Two template specializations `ID_by_T` and `T_by_ID` define `type <=> ID` link at compile time. Type's ID is a enum constant. If `type <=> ID` link is not defined `ID_by_T<type>::ID` is `-1` and `T_by_ID<undefinedID>::type` is `null_t` predefined type. `DEF_TYPE_ID(type_name)` macro generates new ID when defines `type <=> ID` link. `int_triangle` and `char_triangle` show how to get typedef with correct type's ID and inner typedef `_MyID_T` shows how to get ID of type. The code was compiled with MS VS 2005 C++.

The core -- **type_id_map** header file:

```
#ifndef __TYPE_ID_MAP__
#define __TYPE_ID_MAP__

namespace ns_type_ids {
    struct null_t {};
    template<class T, int ID_v>
    struct ID_T_pair {
        enum {ID=ID_v};
        typedef T _Type;
        inline static const _TCHAR * name() { return _T("unknown"); }
    };

    template<class T> struct ID_by_T: ID_T_pair<T, -1> {};
    template<int ID_v> struct T_by_ID: ID_T_pair<null_t, ID_v> {};

    template<> struct ID_by_T<null_t>: ID_T_pair<null_t, -1> {
        inline static const _TCHAR * name() { return _T("null_t"); }
    };
    template<> struct T_by_ID<ID_by_T<null_t>::ID>: ID_by_T<null_t> {};
};

#define PREV_TYPE null_t
#define DEF_TYPE_ID(type_name) \
namespace ns_type_ids { \
    template<> struct ID_by_T<type_name>: ID_T_pair<type_name, ID_by_T<PREV_TYPE>::ID+1> { \
        inline static const _TCHAR * name() { return _T(#type_name); } \
    }; \
    template<> struct T_by_ID<ID_by_T<type_name>::ID>: ID_by_T<type_name> {}; \
};

#endif
```

And the use of *type_id_map* example in **templated_cls_id.cpp**:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _UNICODE
#define _tcout wcout
#else
#define _tcout cout
#endif


#include "type_id_map"    

//targeted types
struct shape {};

template<class T>
struct data_t: shape {
    T _data;
};

template<class T>
struct triangle: data_t<T>, ns_type_ids::ID_by_T<data_t<T> > {
    typedef data_t<T> _MyID_T;
};

//begin type <=> id map
DEF_TYPE_ID(int)
#undef  PREV_TYPE
#define PREV_TYPE int

DEF_TYPE_ID(double)
#undef  PREV_TYPE
#define PREV_TYPE double

DEF_TYPE_ID(float)
#undef  PREV_TYPE
#define PREV_TYPE float

DEF_TYPE_ID(data_t<int>)
#undef  PREV_TYPE
#define PREV_TYPE data_t<int>

DEF_TYPE_ID(data_t<char>)
#undef  PREV_TYPE
#define PREV_TYPE data_t<char>
//end type <=> id map

//Now targeted classes could be defined
typedef triangle<int> int_triangle;
typedef triangle<char> char_triangle;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace ns_type_ids;
#define out_id(type_name) \
    _T("ID_by_T<") _T(#type_name) _T(">::ID: ") << ID_by_T<type_name>::ID
#define out_name(type_id) \
    _T("T_by_ID<") _T(#type_id) _T(">: ") << T_by_ID<type_id>::name()

    _tcout
        << out_id(null_t) << endl
        << out_id(int) << endl
        << out_id(double) << endl
        << out_id(float) << endl
        << out_id(int_triangle::_MyID_T) << endl
        << out_id(char_triangle::_MyID_T) << endl

        << out_name(-1) << endl
        << out_name(0) << endl
        << out_name(1) << endl
        << out_name(2) << endl
        << out_name(3) << endl
        << out_name(4) << endl
    ;
    return 0;
#undef out_id
#undef out_name
}
```

Output:

```
ID_by_T<null_t>::ID: -1
ID_by_T<int>::ID: 0
ID_by_T<double>::ID: 1
ID_by_T<float>::ID: 2
ID_by_T<int_triangle::_MyID_T>::ID: 3
ID_by_T<char_triangle::_MyID_T>::ID: 4
T_by_ID<-1>: null_t
T_by_ID<0>: int
T_by_ID<1>: double
T_by_ID<2>: float
T_by_ID<3>: data_t<int>
T_by_ID<4>: data_t<char>
```

**Requirements and restrictions:**

1. `Type <=> ID` map is global and works only at compile time.
2. `Type <=> ID` link must be defined at global namespace level using `DEF_TYPE_ID` and `PREV_TYPE` macro.
3. "IDed" type must be declared prior to defintion of `Type <=> ID` link.
4. In order to get self ID inside a class use `ID_by_T<self_type>` as a base class where self_type is an own type of class. But why (see below)?
5. In order to get self ID inside a templated class use `ID_by_T<base_data_type>` as a base class where base_data_type is a special base type of templated class for wich `type <=> ID` link is already defined. See `int_triangle` and `char_triangle` for example. Also there are other tricks to get defined ID inside a template instance.

**Features**

- IDs are **external and allocated at compile time automatically sequentially** beginning with 0 in the compilation order of `type <=> ID` link definitions. This is inevitability due to the requirement of the question.
- Minimal requirements to a compiler: only standard features of `ISO/IEC 14882:2003 SE`.
- Macros `__COUNTER__`, `__LINE__`, [`BOOST_PP_COUNTER`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/counter.html) or based on `sizeof` are not used to allocate ID: there are no side effects associated with them.
- The `type <=> id` map is based on external IDs known at compile time:

  - An ID can be assigned to every type, even to a fundamental type.
  - `ID_T_pair` template describes `type <=> id` link. `ID_by_T`/`T_by_ID` templates are direct descendants of `ID_T_pair` template.
  - Due to `ID_by_T` template it is not necessary to define ID inside of a type (what is impossible for fundamental types).
  - ID by type is accessed with `ID_by_T<type>::ID` enum constant.
  - Type by ID is accessed with `T_by_ID<ID>::_Type` inner typedef.
  - Optional: type's name is accessed with `name()` method of `ID_T_pair`.
  - The map does not occupy any memory byte if method `name()` of `ID_T_pair` is not used.
- The map is distributed: `type <=> id` link can be defined in place but at global namespace level.
- In order to access the map in a few TU a special header may be used.
- Definition of a composed derived type does not require any additional info for the map.
- The map uses special null type `null_t` and `ID=-1` returned in absence of `type <=> ID` link.

Comment: This requires that all types be declared in each and every TU, and in the same order.  Might as well simply make a manual enumeration.

Comment: @MooingDuck I've described the solution in more detail. How does manual enumeration allow to work around chaining ID definitions and to get IDs sequential (dense) and unique for every template instance?

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to mention the requirement that the usages of `DEF_TYPE_ID` must be in the same exact order in each cpp file that uses them, or else you get linker errors.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Does it really need to get libraries A (with one type map) and B (with another type map) compatible on binary level on the IDed derived types (which means the header and templates of both are going to be used outside the library with all interfaces) instead of only on language level? I think "a system of classes that are small objects" implies small and effective code which does not need to be deeply compatible on every interface.

Answer (score 3):

Today I've developed another solution to assign ID for every template instance automatically without the need to define an alias for every "IDed" template instance. The solution named v2 is based on previous referred as v1. The v1's feature of assigning an ID to a fundamental type is required to automatically assign unique ID to every template instance.

**UPD: important note on the choosing of the only ID allocator**

The problem addressed here is related to the task but both answers. Approaches of the task implies the only ID allocator due to requirements:

> I could turn on RTTI, but the space cost seems fairly large,
>   especially when the type information can be implemented as a pointer
>   and the object size might be no bigger than a couple of bytes

and

> I want dense, unique type ID's that are available at compile time, so
>   the compiler can perform well, like converting a switch on the type
>   IDs into a constant time jump table, or at least a binary search tree

If more than one ID allocator is used (in a case of several libraries and developers) and TU must be interfaced on IDed types then the only way is to use GUIDs which values are rarefied and non sequential. But also GUID occupies 16 bytes and requires RTTI as well as type reflection. Otherwise in an attempt to build two libraries (which absolutely have different `type <=> id` maps) interfaced on ID of types into one module either a linker generates an error (thanks to @MooingDuck for remarks) or developers will interfere with their different assignments of IDs to types obtained either manually (using v2's `DEF_TYPE_ID` macro) or an ID generator (calling a complier by `AUTO_TYPE_ID` macro).

So there are cases which always are to be reduced to the first in order to use int ID of types:

1. there is the only ID allocator and the only `type <=> ID` map for all TU;
2. interface of TU is not depended on "system of classes that are small objects" with `type <=> ID` links, hence the first case for each TU;
3. a negotiation between developers on `type <=> ID` maps, produced by different ID allocators, is to be accomplished to get the only `type <=> ID` map.

There is another approach but which does not meet *"generate dense IDs"* requirement. The approach allows to get partially automatically generated a structured ID i.e. ID such as `enum {FileID, LocalID}; typedef get_id<arg1_t>::res tmpl_arg_1_ID; ...`. In this case `FileID` must be assigned manually to every file where a `type <=> ID` link is defined. `LocalID` is generated by calling a complier with `__LINE__` macro. `LocalID` of a template is automatically assigned in a manner described below. IDs of template arguments such as `tmpl_arg_1_ID` is obtained automatically using `get_id` template. The main advantage of such structured IDs is that they are static and constant for every library and TU due to a constant content of included files (but versioning becomes a problem). In order to apply such a structured ID a multiple nested switch statements may be used beginning with FileID, then LocalID and so on.

**Features and differences from v1**

- Every template instance takes unique ID automatically and does not require any alias or forward declaration due to ID is allocated and defined as inner enum constant.
- A template takes own unique ID defined as enum constant inside a special "null" instance of a template such as `T<null_t, null_t ...>` named _BaseT where `null_t` type is given for all typename arguments.
- Only IDs of template insnances are rarefied: they are values of hash function calculated from ID of template parameters and template ID accessed as `_BaseT::ID`. Hash function is the same as defined in xhash header in MS VS 2005.
- Now the `type <=> id` map uses **`ID=0`** returned in absence of `type <=> ID` link.
- By default a template instance does not have associated `type <=> ID` link in the map. This is why `get_id` template is used to access ID by type.
- `__COUNTER__` macro is used to reduce and simplify code: `PREV_TYPE` macro does not need anymore.
- There is no need to use the trick with template `data_t` from v1 due to forward declarations and internal template instance's ID.
- Now `type <=> id` link with automatically generated ID is to be defined with `AUTO_TYPE_ID(type_name)` macro.
- Also `type <=> id` link may be defined with an ID allocated by another allocator (i.e. manually) using `DEF_TYPE_ID(type_name, id)` macro. But if you use both macros a resolution of collision ID assignments become a trouble.

The core -- **type_id_map_t_cnt** header

```
#ifndef __TYPE_ID_MAP_T_CNT__
#define __TYPE_ID_MAP_T_CNT__

//use it if there is __COUNTER__ macro and rarefied random ID is allowable
namespace ns_type_ids {
    typedef unsigned int uint;
    typedef unsigned long long ulint;
    typedef unsigned short ushort;

    //`type <=> id` link
    struct null_t { enum {ID=__COUNTER__}; };
    template<class T, int ID_v>
    struct ID_T_pair {
        enum {ID=ID_v};
        typedef T _Type;
        inline static const _TCHAR * name() { return _T("unassigned"); }
    };

    //accessors for `type <=> id` link
    template<class T> struct ID_by_T: ID_T_pair<T, null_t::ID> {};
    template<int ID_v> struct T_by_ID: ID_T_pair<null_t, ID_v> {};

    //predefined `type <=> id` link for null_t and ID=0
    template<> struct ID_by_T<null_t>: ID_T_pair<null_t, null_t::ID> {
        inline static const _TCHAR * name() { return _T("null_t"); }
    };
    template<> struct T_by_ID<ID_by_T<null_t>::ID>: ID_by_T<null_t> {};

    //function for generating IDs inside an instance of class template
    //2166136261U and 16777619U constants are from xhash STL implementation
    template<ushort v, uint a=2166136261U>
    struct hash {
        enum : uint {res=(uint)((ulint)16777619U * (ulint)a ^ (ulint)v)};
    };

    //ternary operator ?:
    template <bool, class Yes, class No>struct IIF { typedef null_t res; };
    template <class Yes, class No> struct IIF<true, Yes, No> { typedef Yes res; };
    template <class Yes, class No> struct IIF<false, Yes, No> { typedef No res; };

    //accessor to ID of type for both `type <=> ID` link and ID of a template instance
    template <class T>
    struct get_id {
        typedef typename IIF<
        //by default there is no `type <=> ID` link for a teamplate instance
        //instead ID is allocated and defined inside.
            ID_by_T<T>::ID == null_t::ID
        ,   T
        ,   ID_by_T<T>
        >::res _IDed;
        // this `::ID` interface coincedences for
        // ID_T_pair, a template instance T and null_t
        enum : uint {res=_IDed::ID};
    };
};

// DEF_TYPE_ID macro to define `type <=> id` link
#define DEF_TYPE_ID(type_name, type_id) \
namespace ns_type_ids { \
    template<> struct ID_by_T<type_name>: ID_T_pair<type_name, type_id> { \
        inline static const _TCHAR * name() { return _T(#type_name); } \
    }; \
    template<> struct T_by_ID<ID_by_T<type_name>::ID>: ID_by_T<type_name> {}; \
};

// AUTO_TYPE_ID macro to allocate new ID and define `type <=> id` link
#define AUTO_TYPE_ID(type_name) DEF_TYPE_ID(type_name, __COUNTER__)

#endif /* __TYPE_ID_MAP_T_CNT__ */
```

The use of `type <=> id` map example in templated_cls_id.cpp

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _UNICODE
#define _tcout wcout
#else
#define _tcout cout
#endif

#include "type_id_map_t_cnt"

//Now `type <=> id` link definition became very short
AUTO_TYPE_ID(int)
AUTO_TYPE_ID(double)
AUTO_TYPE_ID(float)

//Use forward declaration of a template and a specialization with null_t
//to define special base type with ID of the template
template<class T> struct tmpl_id;
template<> struct tmpl_id<ns_type_ids::null_t>;

//Now "null template" is known for the compiler
AUTO_TYPE_ID(tmpl_id<ns_type_ids::null_t>)

//The "null template" specialization
//Realy _BaseT type alias it the "null template" specialization
template<> struct tmpl_id<ns_type_ids::null_t> {
    //returns the same base ID for every class instance
    typedef tmpl_id<ns_type_ids::null_t> _BaseT;
    //generating ID and defining its container
    typedef ns_type_ids::hash<ns_type_ids::ID_by_T<_BaseT>::ID> _Hash;
    //This is the ID of template tmpl_id
    enum {ID=_Hash::res};
};

//Now the target template can be defined.
//tmpl_id<ns_type_ids::null_t> is the base type for all template instances.
//_BaseT is inherited from the base type.
template<class T>
struct tmpl_id: tmpl_id<ns_type_ids::null_t> {
    //unique rarefied calculated ID for every class instance
    typedef ns_type_ids::hash<        
        ns_type_ids::get_id<T>::res
    ,   _BaseT::ID // it is already hash value
                   // and the second calling hash with it is not needed
    > _Hash;
    enum {ID=_Hash::res};
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    using namespace std;
    using namespace ns_type_ids;

    typedef int int_alias; //for testing behaviour on alias of int
    //Now get_id is used instead of direct access with ID_by_T
#define out_id(type_name) \
    _T("ID_by_T<") _T(#type_name) _T(">::ID: ") << get_id<type_name>::res
#define out_name(type_id) \
    _T("T_by_ID<") _T(#type_id) _T(">: ") << T_by_ID<type_id>::name()

    _tcout
        << _T("ID_by_T -- getting ID of type") << endl
        << out_id(null_t) << endl
        << out_id(int) << endl
        <<_T("ID_of_T<type_alias> works as expected") << endl
        << out_id(int_alias) << endl
        << out_id(double) << endl
        << out_id(float) << endl
        << out_id(tmpl_id<null_t>) << endl
        << out_id(tmpl_id<int>) << endl
        << out_id(tmpl_id<double>) << endl
        << out_id(tmpl_id<float>) << endl
        /* Next commented line generates an error to indicate
           absence of ID for the char type */
        //<< out_id(tmpl_id<char>) << endl 
        << endl
        << _T("T_by_ID -- getting type or its name by ID") << endl
        << out_name(-1) << endl
        << out_name(0) << endl
        << out_name(1) << endl
        << out_name(2) << endl
        << out_name(3) << endl
        << out_name(4) << endl
        << out_name(5) << endl
    ;
    return 0;
#undef out_id
#undef out_name
}
```

**Output:**

```
ID_by_T -- getting ID of type
ID_by_T<null_t>::ID: 0
ID_by_T<int>::ID: 1
ID_of_T<type_alias> works as expected
ID_by_T<int_alias>::ID: 1
ID_by_T<double>::ID: 2
ID_by_T<float>::ID: 3
ID_by_T<tmpl_id<null_t>>::ID: 4
ID_by_T<tmpl_id<int>>::ID: 225874304
ID_by_T<tmpl_id<double>>::ID: 225874307
ID_by_T<tmpl_id<float>>::ID: 225874306

T_by_ID -- getting type or its name by ID
T_by_ID<-1>: unassigned
T_by_ID<0>: null_t
T_by_ID<1>: int
T_by_ID<2>: double
T_by_ID<3>: float
T_by_ID<4>: tmpl_id<ns_type_ids::null_t>
T_by_ID<5>: unassigned
```

If you know how to calculate sequential IDs for template instances please let me know to rewrite `ns_type_ids::hash` :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking for is basically impossible in C++. The counter cannot be known at compile time, because individual compilation units do not know about each other, so you're pretty much on a hiding to nothing there.

Instead I'm using the following approach, which still isn't at "compile-time", but at least doesn't incur a function-call overhead when you query the type (assuming the compiler respects the inline), and is threadsafe.

RuntimeID.h

```
//-----------------------------------------------
class CNextRuntimeID 
{
protected:
  static long m_NextRuntimeID;
};

//-----------------------------------------------

template<class T>
class CIntegerRuntimeTypeID: public CNextRuntimeID
{
  static const long m_RuntimeID;
public:
  inline static long GetRuntimeID()
  {
    return m_RuntimeID;
  }
};

template<class T> 
const long CIntegerRuntimeTypeID<T>::m_RuntimeID = CNextRuntimeID::m_NextRuntimeID++;
```

RuntimeID.cpp

```
long CNextRuntimeID::m_NextRuntimeID = 0;
```

I've thought quite a bit about this implementation, and I believe it's safe. A potential issue is that m_NextRuntimeID could in theory be initialised to zero after one of the m_RuntimeIDs are, which would obviously result in duplicate values. However, under VisualStudio at least, the initialisation to zero does not generate code, whereas the counter-based initialisations do.

Unfortunately, if you really care about code space, you may not like the fact that each of the increments are placed inside a function, and those functions take up space. Less space than the usual 'static local variable' non-threadsafe approach, but space nevertheless.