# Uniquely identifiable call to a macro

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

## The context

I am trying to implement an easy to use `async/await` pattern in my C++ code, and I have a way of doing it that I find remarkably simple to use. However, since I am using macros, it also comes at a cost in terms of weakness against exotic code.

Here is the idea:

- We wrap the execution context in a class, whose members are the variables used by the `async` function.
- Inside the body of the `async` function I implement with macros a switch on a member `entrypoint` that I use to keep track where jump to when the execution of the function is resumed:

  ```
  switch(this->entrypoint)
  {
      // All the async code occurs here, like:
      await(this->foo = bar());
      std :: cout << this->foo << std :: endl;
      await(this->foo2 = bar2());
      std :: cout << this->foo2 << std :: endl;
  }
  ```
- The `await(assignment)` macro actually defines something in the form:

  ```
  this->entrypoint = (some value x);
  return;
  case x:
  ```

Now, this is obviously less compact than a full-fledged `async function` we could have, for example, in Javascript, but it is more than enough for my needs. Also this prevents nested switches (which I use very rarely) and you cannot define variables locally unless you wrap them somehow in a `{ /*..*/ }`. But I get a super compact way of doing asynchronous operations with a synchronous style.

**Remark**: The downsides and weaknesses of this strategy are quite clear to me, this is not the point of my question, I just added this to help understand what I need.

## The question

The above compiles and runs nicely. However, I am having a serious problem: in the `await` macro, I need to generate some unique value `x` to use in the `case` statement. So far, I am doing it using `__LINE__`, which works nicely and prevents collisions for most practical purposes. What happens, however, when you write two `await` statements on the same line?

So I wonder: is there a better way than using `__LINE__` to uniquely identify a call to a macro, so that whenever I call the same macro from two distinct places in my code I get different values expanded?

Comment: You could use `__COUNTER__`.

Comment: Nice idea but `__COUNTER__` ain't portable. Perhaps that doesn't matter?

Comment: Why are you using macros? This seems like an incredibly opaque way to write a program.

Comment: @nwp uh, wow, `__COUNTER__` seems exactly what I need. Is it not so widely supported that I might have real-world issues?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit as I said in my remark, I know about the downsides of using macros. I have written asynchronous code with hundreds of different transactions in the past that would stack up to thousands and thousands of line of immensely repetitive code, which made it nearly impossible to maintain. This round I am willing to incur in some opaqueness, but have a readable and maintainable code.

Comment: By "opaque" I mean "not readable and not maintainable" but it's your call!

Comment: Have you tried converting to inline function?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews could you elaborate a bit? Sounds interesting but I am not getting your reference!

Comment: [Benefits of inline functions in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145838/benefits-of-inline-functions-in-c) and on a more general note: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function

Comment: @user4581301 I am really sorry but I am not understanding. What is the connection between inlining a function and what I need to do?

Comment: As stated above, you can use `__COUNTER__` and you need to consider that it is a common predefined macro which means a **GCC extension**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Template instantiation (Unstable)

The type system offers methods of creating compile time variables; however, it does not offer any method of maintaining state between calls.

But, using the method described [here](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/) you can create a `constexpr` counter in the templating system by checking which functions have been created, which may work for you; however, this system depends on some promises from the way gcc generates functions and may not work in the future, it currently fails on clang.

Because everything here operates at compile time (mostly in the type system) you get both the ability to use the values in switch statements and (nearly) zero overhead at runtime.

---

## Macros Making Functions (Global Scope)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6166672/4499969) post describes a method of making a compile time counter entirely out of macros; however, to make the values `constexpr` it creates new functions and can only increment fromm the outside of a function.

---

## `__COUNTER__` Extension

The pre-processor's standard offers no method of requesting a unique value; however, as mentioned in comments [GCC has an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) for `__COUNTER__` that will perform the requested task. This is also supported by [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html).

---

## Not Using Switch

A simple fix (although i don't know enough about your implementation) might be to remove the switch statement in favour of chained if else-if sets.

```
#define aswitch(x) \
    int position_counter=0;
    if(this->entrypoint==position_counter++)
#define await(x) \
    this->entrypoint=position_counter; \
    }else if(this->entrypoint==position_counter++){
aswitch(this->entrypoint)
{
    await(bar());
    std :: cout << this->foo << std :: endl;
    await(bar2());
    std :: cout << this->foo2 << std :: endl;
}
```

Comment: Very nice!! Thank you very much!