# Type deduction time

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

I ran into this problem earlier today. In the following code:

```
template <int> struct Holder {};

template <typename> struct Helper { using T = Holder<__COUNTER__>; };  // ???

int main() {
  auto a = typename Helper<bool>::T();
  auto b = typename Helper<int>::T();

  std::cout << (typeid(a) == typeid(b)) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

When compiled and executed with:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o test
./test
```

It prints out 1 instead of 0, meaning that the 2 Ts in `Helper<int>` and `Helper<bool>` are the same type, which makes me wonder:

1. Why the line marked with `// ???` is executed only once instead of once for each of the type?
2. Is there a way to force the line to be executed once for each of the type and preferably without modifying the definition of Holder?

====================================================
**Clarifications:**

The (closer to) real scenario is:

1. The `struct Holder` is defined in a header from a third-party library. The type for the struct is actually very complicated and the library writer provides users with another macro:

```
template <bool, int> struct Holder {};

#define DEF_HOLDER(b)  Holder<b, __COUNTER__>()
```

At some point of the program, I want to take a "snapshot" of the type with current counter by aliasing the type so that it could be used in a function:

```
template <bool b>
struct Helper { using T = decltype(DEF_HOLDER(b)); };

template <bool b, typename R = typename Helper<b>::T>
R Func() {
  return R();
}

// Note that the following does not work:
// Since the 2 types generated by DEF_HOLDER do not match.
template <bool b>
auto Func() -> decltype(DEF_HOLDER(b)) {
  return DEF_HOLDER(b);
}
```

The problem here is that the following 2 usage has inconsistent semantics as illustrated:

```
int main() {
  auto a = DEF_HOLDER(true);
  auto b = DEF_HOLDER(true);
  auto c = Func<true>();
  auto d = Func<true>();

  std::cout << (typeid(a) == typeid(b)) << std::endl;  // prints 0
  std::cout << (typeid(c) == typeid(d)) << std::endl;  // prints 1

  return 0;
}
```

In my use case, it is important for multiple invocation of `Func` to return different types as it does with invoking `DEF_HOLDER` directly.

Comment: Even though it prints 1 it does not mean that `Helper<int>` and `Helper<bool>` are the same type. They are different types `static_assert(false == ::std::is_same_v<Helper<int>, Helper<bool>>);`. It is not clear what are you trying to achieve here.

Comment: @VTT - The OP is asking about `Helper<bool>::T` and `Helper<int>::T` - which are the same type here.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, but if OP wants to get two different types from the `Helper<bool>` and `Helper<int>` he can use these types themselves. Or make something like `struct T{};` instead of `using T = Holder<__COUNTER__>;`. So it is not clear why would he need that `Holder` type.

Comment: @VTT - I imagine this is some sort of simplified form of an attempt at meta-programming. I agree that this might be an XY problem though.

Comment: @kkspeed - Instead of fixating on question 2, which is what you feel is the solution to your actual problem, would you mind telling us a thing or two about your end goal? Like I said already, this has the feeling of an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) about it.

Comment: @StoryTeller - Please see the clarification. Sry for the confusion.

Comment: Now this makes even less sense. You write *"I want to take a "snapshot" of the type with current counter by aliasing the type so that it could be used in a function"* bun then you complain that returning that snapshotted type from a function yields the same type.

Comment: You simply cannot encapsulate a context dependent macro in a function, type, template, or anything else except possibly another macro.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does C++ support compile-time counters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166337/does-c-support-compile-time-counters)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The symbol `__COUNTER__` is a *preprocessor macro*, it's expanded *once* only.

That means `T` will *always* be `Holder<0>` (since `__COUNTER__` starts at zero), no matter the type used for the template `Helper`.

See e.g. [this GCC predefined macro reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) for more information about `__COUNTER__`.

Comment: Thanks. Please see my clarification. Is there a way to force multiple expansion in this case?

Comment: @kkspeed: Only this way, which is fragile, not standard conforming, difficult to understand and fun ; ): http://b.atch.se/posts/non-constant-constant-expressions/
Here is a standard committee voice over this technique: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2118

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I completely understand the problem, but since C++14 there is no need to use DEF_HOLDER two times. The following code also works:

```
template <bool b>
auto Func() {
   return DEF_HOLDER(b);
}
```

If you want a different type for every function call, you can add the int parameter:

```
template <bool b, int i>
auto Func()
{
  return Holder<b, i>();
}
```

You could hide this int in a macro:

```
#define FUNC(b)  Func<b,__COUNTER__>();
```

Then a,b and c,d have the same semantics:

```
int main() {
  auto a = DEF_HOLDER(true);
  auto b = DEF_HOLDER(true);
  auto c = FUNC(true);
  auto d = FUNC(true);

  std::cout << (typeid(a) == typeid(b)) << std::endl;  // prints 0
  std::cout << (typeid(c) == typeid(d)) << std::endl;  // prints 0

  return 0;
}
```