# C++ logging source line of an object instantiation as a constant expression without a macro

Tags: c++, c++20, constant-expression

I'm playing around with `std::source_location` as a means to define a static identifier for a class which behaves similar to a [compile-time counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166337/does-c-support-compile-time-counters). The basic idea is rather simple: use a class template taking an `integral_constant` as template parameter and at the site of instantiation pass the constant expression `std::source_location::current().line()` to the class.

With the following code using a macro, I can get this behavior without explicitly spelling the `std::source_location`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>

template<typename, typename index>
struct A_impl
{
    static constexpr auto line() { return index::value; }
};

template<template<typename ...> typename temp, typename index>
struct line_manager
{
    template<typename ... Ts>
    using type = temp<Ts ..., index>;
};

#define A typename line_manager<A_impl, std::integral_constant<int, std::source_location::current().line()> >::type
```

This can be used as in the following code and allows to separate the two object instantiations at compile time:

```
int main()
{
    A<double> a; //expands to A_impl<double, integral_constant<int, line()> >
    A<double> b;
    
    if constexpr(a.line() != b.line())
    {
        std::cout<<a.line()<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<b.line()<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/EcvP86s31)

Can the same behavior as in the code above -- i.e. logging the source line as a constant expression without explicitly specifying it in the instantiation -- can also be obtained without a macro?

Side note: I know that the above code is not functional, as you could also write `A<double> a,b` and obtain the same line. That doesn't matter here.

Comment: I suspect the answer is "no", since you're relying on `std::source_location::current().line()` being evaluated at each point where you define (in your examples) instances of `A<double>`.    Not using a macro will tend to cause `std::source_location::current().line()` to be evaluated at the point where you defined the types, not the instances of those types.

Comment: From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/current), the only special places where value is **'moved'** are for default member initializer and function default argument (and from standard, it was just a remark)...

Comment: Currently, type of `a` and `b` differs. storing `std::source_location` as member of `A_Impl` might allow you to pass `current()` in constructor and have the different value as expected...

Comment: @Jarod42: yes, but as far I can see then it's not a constant expression by definition. The `if constexpr` is crucial here.

Comment: @davidhigh: It is indeed no longer constant expression (unless `a` and `b` are marked `constexpr`)

Answer (score 2):

I come up a way without using macros or direct spelling `std::source_location::current().line()`, but still needs a bit extra work.

The main idea is to construct a literal type that contains the line number since `std::source_location` is not literal.

```cpp
struct Line {
    int line;
    constexpr Line(std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current()): line(loc.line()) {}
};
```

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/current):

> If current() is used in a default argument, the return value corresponds to the location of the call to current() at the call site.

So we don't construct a `Line` until we really need it.

```cpp
template <typename T, Line L>
struct Logger {
    constexpr static auto line() {
        return L.line;
    }
};
```

Here `Logger` is equivalent to `A` in your case. Then here we go,

```cpp
Logger<int, {}> x; // x.line() refer to here
Logger<int, {}> y; // y.line() refer to here
std::cout << x.line() << "\n";
std::cout << y.line() << "\n";
```

[Demo on GCC and MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/qbT84asnj)

The only extra thing here you need is to pass `{}` as the second template argument.

([Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Gjjs5Exsv) complains, you have to spell `Logger<int, Line{}>` and you'll get the wrong results.
It seems Clang's `std::source_location::current().line()` implementation doesn't conform the standard. Just let it go...)

---

You may wonder what if you just use `{}` as the default argument for `Line`.

See [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TMobYfTcr), GCC works as expected but MSVC refers to the line `template <typename T, Line line = {}` resides.

BUT I think maybe MSVC conforms more to the standard here.

Comment: *"doesn't conform the standard"*. From [support.srcloc.cons](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.srcloc#cons-1.1), most results are implementation-defined. Not sure how the remark apply to `template`. Especially, with that divergence, type of `x`, `y` might be identical or different :-/

Comment: Even though these values are implementation-defined, they shoud be consistent with macros `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`.  Take a look at this case https://godbolt.org/z/eqP394h93 Clang's result is apparently unexpected(inconsistent with cases in the remark) unless its macro has an unintuitive value... Also clang can't give the correct function name either.

Comment: *Not sure how the remark apply to template. Especially, with that divergence, type of x, y might be identical or different :-/* The question seems turned into when the expression in templates evaluated. I'm not sure if there's someplace in the standard about this.