# Is it possible to deduce whether type is incomplete without compilation failure?

Tags: c++, templates, incomplete-type, template-argument-deduction

I want to achieve behavior like sizeof(complete_type) will return real sizeof, and sizeof(incomplete_type) - will be just 0

I need this to provide extended run time type information for IPC(inter-process) communication with the description structure per type:

```
struct my_type_info
{
    bool   is_pointer;
    size_t size;         //for double* will be 4 on i386. that is sizeof(double*)
    size_t base_size;    //for double* will be 8. that is sizeof(double)
};
```

The problem appears when into my system goes something like class MyOnlyDeclaredClass; I got compilation error, obviously by reason I can't take size of it.

boost type_traits http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html suggests many compile-time classes, but there is no 'is_incomplete'

Interesting compilers are VS2008, VS2010, clang 3, gcc-4.6, gcc-4.7

Comment: And what are you going to do if you detect that the type is incomplete? Throw a static_assert error?

Comment: No if pointer lays in shared memory, I can just pass it to another process without knowing what it is the type. Pointer can be easy passed by subtraction shared memory base from its value.

Comment: I still don't seem to understand it. Why don't you pass all the pointers (both of complete and incomplete types) that way?

Comment: because in my system presents another kind of pointers - like interfaces that should be passed to another process in another way. Additionally it will allow to check at runtime from which kind of memory the pointer goes. I admit an ability to resolve task in another not so much elegant way.

Comment: Please tell us more about what you really need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), as usual. This is one possible implementation:

```
struct char256 { char x[256]; };

template <typename T>
char256 is_complete_helper(int(*)[sizeof(T)]);

template <typename>
char is_complete_helper(...);

template <typename T>
struct is_complete
{
    enum { value = sizeof(is_complete_helper<T>(0)) != 1 };
};
```

Example:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct F;
struct G {};

int main()
{
    printf("%d %d\n", is_complete<F>::value, is_complete<G>::value);
    return 0;
}
```

(Note: Works on [gcc 4.5](http://ideone.com/TmBef) (no it's not because of C++0x) and clang 2.9, [but not gcc 4.3](http://ideone.com/3PpXk))

Comment: By the way, this is the trick used in `boost::checked_delete`.

Comment: Wow! I could not thought in such way before.

Comment: Test result: VS2008/VS2010 (both with SP1): Error C2027 use of undefined type 'F'. g++-4.7 - works, clang - works with warning.

Comment: `struct T; int i=(cout<<is_complete<T>::value,i); struct T{}; int j=(cout<<is_complete<T>::value,i);` lol

Comment: 00 by fact (clang 3 -std=c++0x) :( remembers generated instance ... The effect boost::shared_ptr uses to remember completed type that allows it to be deleted without visibility of the type header.

Answer (score 12):

## Do not try to do that.

It is fundamentally unsound. Templates are parametrized by types, not instantiation point. A class type is not complete or not in itself, it is complete at some point during translation.

A template instantiated on some types must have the exact same semantic in every instantiation.

If not, **the behaviour is not defined.**

Comment: +1. I was just about to scream like that too. The while idea is fundamentally broken.

Comment: Well, I actually have a reasonably valid usecase for this. I've been doing a little wrapper-generator tool that exports C++ functions to other languages, and I decided to not even try to parse C++ but use variadic templates to take the function declarations apart. In some of these cases I now use the is_complete to check whether certain classes are derived "as required", and just assume they are if the classes aren't known to the wrapper tool. Compiling the C++ will fail anyway if the classes are not according to specs; it just fails earlier if the tool can already do the check.