# Expecting different types depending of point of instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-instantiation

I expect the following to be ill formed NDR, but it seems not :-(

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename Enabler = void>
struct is_complete : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_complete<T, std::void_t<decltype(sizeof(T) != 0)>> : std::true_type {};

class X;

static_assert(!is_complete<X>::type{}); // incomplete type

class X {};

static_assert(!is_complete<X>::type{}); // complete, but already instantiated
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c95cb0352f063d40)

*Note*: Assuming `sizeof(T) != 0` is valid for completeness traits (as no types can have `sizeof(T) == 0`, using other constant would force to find a better name for the traits :-) )

It is a variation of the code from [Is a specialization implicitly instantiated if it has already been implicitly instantiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201121/is-a-specialization-implicitly-instantiated-if-it-has-already-been-implicitly-in), where the program has been declared ill-formed program, No Diagnostic Required (NDR), as the **method** `is_complete_helper<X>::test<X>`  has 2 different meanings depending of the points of instantiation.

References which seems near to make the program ill formed, but doesn't as I understand:

- http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.5

> the interpretation of such a construct in the hypothetical instantiation is different from the interpretation of the corresponding construct in any actual instantiation of the template.

- http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#temp.point-8

> A specialization for a function template, a member function template, or of a member function or static data member of a class template may have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, and in addition to the points of instantiation described above, for any such specialization that has a point of instantiation within the translation unit, the end of the translation unit is also considered a point of instantiation. A specialization for a class template has at most one point of instantiation within a translation unit. A specialization for any template may have points of instantiation in multiple translation units. If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

I'm wrong ? or unfortunately this program is correct.

Comment: I believe a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8452846/1708801) and this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1625105/1708801) covers your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I expect the following to be ill formed NDR, but it seems not :-(

You cannot use the fact that a program compiles (and runs) as evidence that it is not ill-formed, NDR. In the same way that you cannot use seemingly valid output of a program to demonstrate that it doesn't exhibit undefined behavior.

That said, the relevant rule here is [[temp.point]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#point-8.sentence-4):

> A specialization for a class template has at most one point of instantiation within a translation unit. A specialization for any template may have points of instantiation in multiple translation units. If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

We just have one point of instantiation of `is_complete<X>`: which is right before the first `static_assert`. So, this is "fine" - it's arguably confusing and bad, but it's well-formed.

But, however, if we split this up:

```
// a.cpp
struct X;
static_assert(!is_complete<X>::value);

// b.cpp
struct X { };
static_assert(is_complete<X>::value);
```

Now this is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

---

Note, you don't need `sizeof(T) != 0`. Just `sizeof(T)` is fine. You cannot take `sizeof` of an incomplete type, so you simply need to check that `sizeof(T)` is a valid expression.

Comment: Right. I was confused for a moment :)

Comment: My *"it seems not"* was mostly due to the discussion from the linked question, and indeed compiler cannot be used for NDR proof ;-) . Sad that the code is correct :-(, especially when small "innocent" variation make it ill formed (as using explicitly a static data member `value` instead of inheritance of `bool_constant` for example).