# Is a specialization implicitly instantiated if it has already been implicitly instantiated?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, template-instantiation, implicit-instantiation

The question in the title is clear enough. To be more specific, consider the following example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct is_complete_helper {
    template <typename U>
    static auto test(U*)  -> std::integral_constant<bool, sizeof(U) == sizeof(U)>;
    static auto test(...) -> std::false_type;
    using type = decltype(test((T*)0));
};

template <typename T>
struct is_complete : is_complete_helper<T>::type {};

// The above is an implementation of is_complete from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21121104/5376789

template<class T> class X;

static_assert(!is_complete<X<char>>::type{}); 
// X<char> should be implicitly instantiated here, an incomplete type

template<class T> class X {};

static_assert(!is_complete<X<char>>::type{}); // #1

X<char> ch; // #2
```

This code [compiles with GCC and Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/TVhzVC).

According to [[temp.inst]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#1.sentence-1):

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the class template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires a completely-defined object type or **when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program**.

`X<char>` is implicitly instantiated due to `static_assert(!is_complete<X<char>>::type{})`, which generates an incomplete type.

Then, after the definition of `X`, `#1` suggests that `X<char>` is not instantiated again (still incomplete) while `#2` suggests that `X<char>` is indeed instantiated again (becomes a complete type).

Is a specialization implicitly instantiated if it has already been implicitly instantiated? Why is there a difference between `#1` and `#2`?

An interpretation from the standard is welcome.

Comment: IIRC, this breaks the odr.

Comment: @YSC Do you mean #1 and #2 break the odr? But it is so common that a specialization is referred to multiple times...

Comment: I was wrong, it would have break the odr if multiple TU were involed, as per [temp.point]/8.

Comment: I think the program is ill formed NDR as `is_complete<X<char>>::type` depends of instantiation point (including EOF one).

Comment: @Jarod42 - The EOF one is only for functions. Classes have only a single POI.

Comment: Hopefully, nobody will have the idea to define is_complete in a header file !!

Comment: I think [temp.res#8.5](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.5) applies.

Answer (score 4):

> Is a specialization implicitly instantiated if it has already been implicitly instantiated?

No. According to [[temp.point]/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.point#8):

> A specialization for a class template has at most one point of instantiation within a translation unit.

`x<char>` need only be instantiated once, and it's not when it's named in the first static assertion, only before `ch`. But, [temp.point]/8 also says

> A specialization for a function template, a member function template,
>   or of a member function or static data member of a class template may
>   have multiple points of instantiations within a translation unit, and
>   in addition to the points of instantiation described above, for any
>   such specialization that has a point of instantiation within the
>   translation unit, the end of the translation unit is also considered a
>   point of instantiation. [...] If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

And `is_complete_helper::test` *is* a member function template whose declaration is instantiated before the static assertion. So it must also have an instantiation at the end of the TU. Where it will likely give a different result. So this trait is depending on an ill-formed NDR construct.

Comment: So is it a bug that #2 compiles?

Comment: @xskxzr - The bug is in assuming `is_complete` can report different things.

Comment: Oh I see the problem of `is_complete`. But why does `#2` compile? Isn't `X<char>` always incomplete according to your interpretation?

Comment: @xskxzr - I see what you mean to ask. Just a sec.

Comment: @xskxzr - Cleaned up the mess that was my ramble. Is it clear now?

Comment: I have emphasized "... or when the completeness of the class type affects the semantics of the program". Doesn't the completeness of `X<char>` affect the semantics of the program?

Comment: @Jarod42 - That applies to the template definition itself. Are you saying is_complete itself is ill-formed NDR?

Comment: @xskxzr - No. The semantics of this single TU is to report false. It doesn't contradict the fact classes can be completed. It just means is_complete, as written cannot report the most up to date info, because it can only be instantiated once for *any type* in a single TU.

Comment: I think so, in one case `test(X*)` doesn't "exists" in one place, and does in the other place.

Comment: @StoryTeller I mean in the first `static_assert`, if `X<char>` is complete, the `static_assert` fails, and if `X<char>` is incomplete, the `static_assert` does not fail, so I conclude that the completeness of `X<char>` affects the semantics of the program, thus `X<char>` need to be implicitly instantiated in the first `static_assert`. What's wrong with this inference？

Comment: @xskxzr - The assumption that `is_complete` must adjust its report based on the completeness of its argument in a single TU. It doesn't. It has a single well-defined point of instantiation. It can only report what it was instantiated with *there*.

Comment: @Jarod42 - The hypothetical instantiation of `is_complete` immediately after its definition cannot be with `X<char>` (there is no `X` declared there). There really is no issue with the test, other than the fact it doesn't update itself when a type is completed in a TU. But that's intentional.

Comment: @xskxzr - You must also remember that there is no looking into the future to know if the type will be instantiated later in the TU. There is one well-defined instantiation point for `is_complete<X<char>>`, and that is before the static assertion. After which, it will not be instantiated again. I can see why this is unexpected (given the template's suggestive name), but I don't believe it's UB.

Comment: @StoryTeller So doesn't the completeness of `X<char>` *there* affect the semantics of the program?

Comment: @xskxzr - No, because `is_complete<X<char>>`  along with all of its members is only instantiated *once*, and never again in this TU.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry I still don't get your point... As I said, "if `X<char>` is complete, the `static_assert` fails, and if `X<char>` is incomplete, the `static_assert` does not fail, so I conclude that the completeness of `X<char>` affects the semantics of the program", all I said is about the first instantiation of `is_complete<X<char>>`, I never mean `is_complete<X<char>>` will be instantiated multiple times...

Comment: @xskxzr - Let's flip this around a bit. Is my last example ill-formed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179538/discussion-between-xskxzr-and-storyteller).

Comment: Wait... is `is_complete_helper::test` really instantiated since the substitution of types results in a deduction failure?

Comment: @xskxzr - There has to be an attempt to instantiate that declaration ([temp.inst/8](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#8)) for substitution to fail. Though you raise a good point. Does it count for the purposes of [temp.point]/8? I think it should, but I find nothing conclusive.