# Can you violate ODR with structured bindings on a class type

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, one-definition-rule, c++17, structured-bindings

The structured bindings feature says that it goes with the tuple like decomposition if the `tuple_size` template is a complete type.  What happens when `std::tuple_size` is a complete type for the given type at one point in the program and is not complete at another point?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Something {
public:
    template <std::size_t Index>
    auto get() {
        cout << "Using member get" << endl;
        return std::get<Index>(this->a);
    }

    std::tuple<int> a{1};
};

namespace {
    auto something = Something{};
}

void foo() {
    auto& [one] = something;
    std::get<0>(one)++;
    cout << std::get<0>(one) << endl;
}

namespace std {
template <>
class tuple_size<Something> : public std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1> {};
template <>
class tuple_element<0, Something> {
public:
    using type = int;
};
}

int main() {
    foo();
    auto& [one] = something;
    cout << one << endl;
}
```

(Reproduced here https://wandbox.org/permlink/4xJUEpTAyUxrizyU)

In the above program the type `Something` is decomposed via the public data members at one point in the program and falls back to the tuple like decomposition at another.  Are we violating ODR with the implicit "is `std::tuple_size` complete" check behind the scenes?

Comment: @DanielLangr which partial specialization are you referring to?

Comment: Why do you think the check "is `std::tuple_size` complete" will violate ODR?

Comment: @xskxzr An `is_complete` trait might result in two different instantiations from existing.  One when the type is complete and another when the type is not complete, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625105/for an example of such a trait

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any reason to believe that the *program in question* is ill-formed. Simply having something in the code depend on the completeness of a type, then having something else later on depend on the completeness of the same type where the type has since been completed, does not violate the standard.

A problem arises if we have something like

```
inline Something something;  // external linkage
inline void foo() {
    auto& [one] = something;
}
```

defined in multiple translation units, where, in some of those, `std::tuple_size<Something>` is already complete at the point where `foo` is defined, and in others, it isn't. This seems like it should definitely violate the ODR, since the entity `one` receives different types in different copies of `foo`, however, I can't actually find a place in the standard that says so. The criteria for the multiple definitions to be merged into one are:

> - each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
> - in each definition of D, corresponding names, looked up according to 6.4, shall refer to an entity defined
>     within the definition of D, or shall refer to the same entity, after overload resolution (16.3) and after
>     matching of partial template specialization (17.8.3), except that a name can refer to
>
>   - a non-volatile const object with internal or no linkage if the object
>
>     - has the same literal type in all definitions of D,
>     - is initialized with a constant expression (8.20),
>     - is not odr-used in any definition of D, and
>     - has the same value in all definitions of D,
>
>     or
>   - a reference with internal or no linkage initialized with a constant expression such that the reference
>       refers to the same entity in all definitions of D;
>
>   and
> - in each definition of D, corresponding entities shall have the same language linkage; and
> - in each definition of D, the overloaded operators referred to, the implicit calls to conversion functions,
>     constructors, operator new functions and operator delete functions, shall refer to the same function, or
>     to a function defined within the definition of D; and
> - in each definition of D, a default argument used by an (implicit or explicit) function call is treated as if
>     its token sequence were present in the definition of D; that is, the default argument is subject to the
>     requirements described in this paragraph (and, if the default argument has subexpressions with default
>     arguments, this requirement applies recursively) 28 ; and
> - if D is a class with an implicitly-declared constructor (15.1), it is as if the constructor was implicitly
>     defined in every translation unit where it is odr-used, and the implicit definition in every translation
>     unit shall call the same constructor for a subobject of D.

If there's a rule here that makes my code ill-formed, I don't know which one it is. Perhaps the standard needs to be amended, because it cannot have been intended that this was allowed.

Another way to make the program ill-formed NDR involves the use of a template:

```
template <int unused>
void foo() {
    auto& [one] = something;
}
// define tuple_element and tuple_size
foo<42>(); // instantiate foo
```

This would run afoul of [temp.res]/8.4, according to which

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if ... the interpretation of [a construct that does not depend on a template parameter] in [the hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition] is different from the interpretation of the corresponding construct in any actual instantiation of the template

Comment: How would the last one violate ODR?  We are only instantiating the function once?  And so we get the same definition that one time.

Comment: @Curious The actual instantiation is compared with the hypothetical instantiation that occurs immediately after the definition.