# How to detect a field with incomplete type using SFINAE?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I have a trait class that implements some interface depending on whether its template parameter type is defined or not:

```
template<class T, class=void>
struct traits {
   // impl for undefined types
};

template<class T>
struct traits<T, decltype(void(sizeof(T)))> {
   // impl for defined types
};
```

This works fine, however I get an error when the type is defined but has a member with incomplete type, for instance when passing an instance of some class template where the template parameter is itself undefined.

Therefore I would like to know if there exists some SFINAE-fu to detect defined types with incomplete fields.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm pretty sure the answer is "no". Though I wonder what could be the use of knowing that a type is "partially" defined.

Comment: Thanks. A bit of context: I have a class implementing recursive algebraic datatypes on top of some `std::variant`-like type. I use the trait class to automatically detect and box/unbox recursive types, which are undefined at the time of the ADT template instantiation. This works perfectly and I use it to represent an abstract syntax tree. But now I want to mix in CRTP in order to attach arbitrary info to my AST nodes and the above problem happens.

Comment: For some reason the specialization for defined types is selected, which triggers an error related to some field having undefined type. I would have thought this would be a substitution error and the specialization for undefined types would be selected instead, but this does not seems to be the case, at least with a recent clang.

Comment: `is_complete` traits is dangerous as it can easily break ODR (-> ill formed program NDR :-/).

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625105/how-to-write-is-complete-template