# SFINAE detect if type is defined

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I want to pick a specialization of a template when a certain type is defined.

I still cannot wrap my head around SFINAE :(. I might be close or I might be completely off. I tried different things and this is something, I at least hope to understand why it does not work (`is_complete` basically stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37193089/4117728)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, class = void>
struct is_complete : std::false_type {};

template <typename T> 
struct is_complete<T,decltype(void(sizeof(T)))> : std::true_type {};

// this should be called if foo is not defined
void test() { std::cout << "test base\n"; }

// forward declare foo
struct foo;

// this should be called if foo is defined    
template <typename T>
std::enable_if<is_complete<foo>::value,void> test() {
  foo::bar();
}

// this is either defined or not
struct foo{
  static void bar() { std::cout << "foo bar\n"; }
};

int main(){
  test();
}
```

With gcc 4.8 (`-std=c++11`) i get :

```
if_type_defined.cpp: In instantiation of ‘struct is_complete<foo>’:
if_type_defined.cpp:16:32:   required from here
if_type_defined.cpp:8:42: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘foo’
 struct is_complete<T,decltype(void(sizeof(T)))> : std::true_type {};
                                          ^
if_type_defined.cpp:8:42: error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘foo’
if_type_defined.cpp: In function ‘std::enable_if<true, void> test()’:
if_type_defined.cpp:17:3: error: incomplete type ‘foo’ used in nested name specifier
   foo::bar();
   ^
```

I think I know more or less what is wrong: `foo` does not depend on `T`, hence no substitution needed to get `foo` and I get a hard error instead of Not An Error. Next I tried to use a helper along the line of

```
template <typename T>
struct make_foo_dependent { 
   using type = foo;
};
```

and tried to use that inside the `enable_if` instead of `foo` directly. However, this just added more errors and I didnt include it here, because I am afraid this is also going in the wrong direction.

**How can I choose what function to call depending on whether `foo` is defined? If `foo` is not defined, the code using `foo` should not issue a hard error, but simply be ignored by the compiler.**

PS: Lots has changed with respect to SFINAE, and I find it hard to find ressources that restrict themself to C++11, where things seem to be a bit more hairy than in newer standards.

Comment: "this should be called if foo is defined" - but `test();` will never invoke that function because it is a template that requires at least one argument.

Comment: @VTT oh, right :). As I mentioned, I am on a complete loss on SFINAE, I just try random stuff and rarely I get what i want

Comment: [The trick with `make_foo_dependent` should've worked](https://godbolt.org/z/EQAYKv). It is actually a right direction.

Comment: @VTT it compiles , but it always calls the non-template `foo`, I guess it can only work when also the base case is a template. Dont remember where i got the idea that it can be non-template

Comment: Care with `struct is_complete` and code (SFINAE) based on it. You quickly can have ODR violations NDR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, as you said, you should make `test` depending on the template parameter `T`; and better making both the overloads template. e.g.

```
// this should be called if foo is not defined
template <typename T = foo>
typename std::enable_if<!is_complete<T>::value,void>::type test() { std::cout << "test base\n"; }

// this should be called if foo is defined    
template <typename T = foo>
typename std::enable_if<is_complete<T>::value,void>::type test() {
  T::bar();
}
```

then call it as

```
test(); // or test<foo>();
```

[LIVE (foo is defined)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jtyANm3nUhni8tYa)
[LIVE (foo is not defined)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xlfWpTIWwZ9c8831)

<sup>BTW: From your intent, I think the return type of `test` should be `typename std::enable_if<is_complete<T>::value,void>::type` instead of `std::enable_if<is_complete<foo>::value,void>`; which is just the type of an instantiation of `std::enable_if` itself.</sup>